npm install --prefix server not working on windows npm version 10.7.0
npm install

from server directory is working fine. but npm install --prefix server from one level up is not working.
I am using powershell inside visual studio code, I tried running powershell as adminstrator and ran this command still got error.
Package.json
{
  "name": "nasa_launch_api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "src/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch": "nodemon src/server.js",
    "start": "set PORT=5000&& node src/server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "Nasa mission control Project",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "csv-parse": "^5.5.5",
    "express": "^4.19.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0"
  }
}

I have removed node-modules and package-lock.json and tried again it fails.

More details about OS
Edition Windows 11 Home Single Language,
Version 23H2,
Installed on ‎06-‎09-‎2023,
OS build 22631.3447,
